# C# Form, trying to change random pictureBox to a random image with timer

Tags: c#, forms

What I'm trying to do is this:

I want the 4 pictureBoxes I got in the form to get the faces of card - turn them over I mean. a random card from the 4 will be chosen, turned over and show the face of the card being chosen also randomley.

Once a card is turned over, it cant be turend over again in the next timer interval, and once all cards had been turned over, a messageBox appears and once the user presses ok, it all restarts.

Problem is: the messageBox keeps appearing over and over again, because of the flag positive value. I don't know which variable should I use to prevent that from happening.

Relevant code:

```
//This function is the timer's function, it starts every time interval:
    private void cardsChangingTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int chosenImage = rnd.Next(1, 17);
        int chosenCard = rnd.Next(0, 4);
        if (bucketArr[chosenCard] == 0)
        {
            bucketArr[chosenCard]++;
            switch (chosenCard)
            {
                case 0:
                    card1Pic.Image = Image.FromFile("cards\\" + chosenImage + ".png");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    card2Pic.Image = Image.FromFile("cards\\" + chosenImage + ".png");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    card3Pic.Image = Image.FromFile("cards\\" + chosenImage + ".png");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    card4Pic.Image = Image.FromFile("cards\\" + chosenImage + ".png");
                    break;

            }
        }
        gameEnded = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < bucketArr.Length; i++) 
        {
            if (bucketArr[i] == 0)
            {
                gameEnded = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (gameEnded)
        {
            DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show("All 4 cards were turned over...");
            if (dialog == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                card1Pic.Image = Image.FromFile("..\\..\\17.png");
                card2Pic.Image = Image.FromFile("..\\..\\17.png");
                card3Pic.Image = Image.FromFile("..\\..\\17.png");
                card4Pic.Image = Image.FromFile("..\\..\\17.png");
            }
            gameEnded = false;
            for(int i = 0; i < bucketArr.Length; i++)
                bucketArr[i] = 0;
        }
    }
```

Thanks alot for any help...

Comment: Use the debugger! You do set gameended to true, right? Does the logic after make sense to you?

Comment: No it doesn't... I know it opens the dialog message box again and again because of it. It just that I'm trying to find a variable solution for that with no luck...

Comment: I think I just need to change the way I find out if the array has a zero in it or not anymore in the middle for loop... I just don't know how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having is the timer is continuing to run while the dialog box is shown. Simply stop the timer before the MessageBox is shown then restart the timer after the box returns.

```
private void cardsChangingTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int chosenImage = rnd.Next(1, 17);
    int chosenCard = rnd.Next(0, 4);

    /// ... Rest of the code goes here

            break;
        }
    }
    if (gameEnded)
    {
        //Get a reference to the timer and stop it.
        var timer = (Timer)sender;
        timer.Stop();

        DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show("All 4 cards were turned over...");
        if (dialog == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            card1Pic.Image = Image.FromFile("..\\..\\17.png");
            card2Pic.Image = Image.FromFile("..\\..\\17.png");
            card3Pic.Image = Image.FromFile("..\\..\\17.png");
            card4Pic.Image = Image.FromFile("..\\..\\17.png");
        }
        gameEnded = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < bucketArr.Length; i++)
            bucketArr[i] = 0;

        //start the timer here after everything has been re-initialized.
        timer.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Scott! Works!! Didn't know you could do that. Thanks alot.